# How do I plot the differential of this function?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, differential-equations

Suppose I have this function:

$$z(x,y) = \left| \frac{ \frac{1}{3x +iy} -2x}{iy + \frac{1}{x}} \right| $$

I want the contour plot of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ with axes $(x,y)$. Tried this code, but didn't work.

```
z = Abs[ ( (1/3 x + I y) - 2 x )/ (I y + 1/x) ]
ContourPlot[D[z[x, y],x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

This seems rather straightforward, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: One issue is that you defined `z` as an expression but you're using it as a function. Another issue might be the derivative of `Abs`; try using `ComplexExpand`.`

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: You can do `z[x_,y_]=ComplexExpand[..., TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}]`.

Comment: Following what @b.gatessucks said you have [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9R0Dz.png).

Comment: @Öskå Ha, you beat me to it :).

Comment: @user44840 As [Artes said](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56629/how-do-i-plot-the-differential-of-this-function#comment162428_56632) you have a mistake in your _Mathematica_ code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks) said in the comments, there are two issues with your code. First, you'll need to define `z` as a function with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), and also add in `ComplexExpand`:

```
z[x_, y_] := ComplexExpand @ Abs[((1/3 x + I y) - 2 x)/(I y + 1/x)];

z[x,y]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[(25 x^2)/9 + y^2] / Sqrt[x^-2 + y^2]
> ```

Additionally, [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) [holds its arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html) (i.e. it doesn't evaluate them), so you'll also need to throw in an [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) to successfully plot the contours:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ D[z[x, y], x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Since b.gatessucks precisely said it, why not letting him/her answer and take the credits for what he/she said? :)

Comment: @Öskå Fair enough; if / when he posts an answer I'll delete this. In the meantime, I've change it to a community wiki.

Comment: `(1/3 x + I y)` is different than `1/(3 x + I y)`.

Comment: @Artes That's the OP's fault :P

Comment: @TeakeNutma I don't mean to blame you for this, there are a few questions already answered in the comments which get answered by someone else, I (is it just me?) just think that it's better to ask the original answerer before posting :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to split the derivative into two parts (real + imaginary) and then make the corresponding contour plots like this

```
z[x_, y_] := Abs[((1/3 x + I y) - 2 x)/(I y + 1/x)];
dx[x_, y_] := D[z[x, y], x]
real = Re[ComplexExpand[dx[x, y]]];
img = Im[ComplexExpand[dx[x, y]]];
ContourPlot[real, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50]
ContourPlot[img, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

The contour of the real part

[image]

and that of the imaginary

[image]

Comment: AddSomePictures.png.

Comment: Do I still need to do ContourPlot[{(real)^2 + (img)^2},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}] because by defining $z$ to be the absolute function,thus $z$ is real, and so $dx$ must be real?